# mod_rewrite with two servers and three subdomains?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns

I've been looking around (both here and the googles), and I can't find an answer that actually works for me. Basically, I have two physical servers (a dev server and a production server), and I want to be able to use one .htaccess file in my git repo.

Normally this wouldn't be difficult, but I have two domains, `example.com` and `longexample.com`. I set up `longexample.com` and `dev.longexample.com`'s CNAMEs to `example.com` (and `dev.example.com`) at my DNS host, and set the apache ServerName/ServerAlias on both servers:

```
dev server:
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAlias dev.longexample.com

prod server:
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias longexample.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.longexample.com
```

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.longexample.com$ [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^longexample.com$ [NC,OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,N]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.longexample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ ([^\.]+)\.(html|htm) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(html|htm)$ %1 [R,NC,L]
```

Supposedly the first two blocks should rewrite prod and dev to the proper urls (I'll make them 301s when everything works), but it doesn't seem to be working. Like it is now, it does nothing. If I set the RewriteRule to `[N]` instead of `[L]`, it gives me an infinite loop.

The first block is commented out because if I get it working on the dev server, the solution for prod should be readily apparent. The last block makes a request to `example.com/about.html` redirect to `example.com/about` (while still using the `/about.html` file. That part works fine.

Is there some issue with using two domains? I've also tried using `%{SERVER_NAME}` instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}`, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, figured it out! It seems having a chain of `[OR]`'s messes it up. Here's what works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoshokatana\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoshokatana\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yosho.me/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yosho\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yosho.me/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.yoshokatana\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.yosho.me/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ ([^\.]+)\.(html|htm) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(html|htm)$ %1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question will show as "Resolved"

Comment: Please read clever advices from Yahoo Slow here http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html and go to the section "Use Cookie-free Domains for Components" and you'll understand why it's bad to redirect to URLs without "www"